# $f \geqslant 0$ and $f''\leqslant 0$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable. Suppose $f \geqslant 0$ and $f''\leqslant 0$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist.

My attempt was, as $f$ is concave, to pass by next inequalities:

Let $a<b<x$ so we have

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}>\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$

and then pass to limit and observe that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is bounded as $x$ goes to $\infty$. But, then i recognised that it doesn't hold...

So i need some help please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $f'(x)$ is decreasing the limit
$$
L=\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)
$$
exists, and it is either a number or $- \infty$.

Now, by L'Hopital (note that you need the version $\frac{\mbox{something}}{\infty}$) , the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
exists and
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=L
$$
Finally, since $f \geq 0$ you have $L \geq 0$, which implies that it is finite.

Answer (score 4):

As you noticed, $f$ is concave, so that for $0 < x < y$
$$
 f(x) \ge \frac{y-x}{y-0} f(0) + \frac{x-0}{y-0} f(y) \ge \frac x y f(y) \\
\implies \frac{f(x)}{x} \ge \frac{f(y)}{y} \, .
$$
So $f(x)/x$ is decreasing and bounded below (by zero) and therefore convergent.

Note that the conclusion holds for all non-negative concave functions, even if they are not differentiable.